# How to solve Vue </script> tag problem in string

Tags: javascript, string, vue.js

In Vue CLI `.vue` files each time I try to use `<script>...</script>` it's giving me an error which says:

> Parsing error: Unterminated string constant iv try this  `'<script>...<\/script>'`

but this gives another error

> Unnecessary escape character: /

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to solve it?

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: actually I solve that problem by adding // eslint-disable-next-line but still can't understand why that's happening

Comment: It is difficult to give you any information about a code that you don't share with us.